# No Rspec gem found in sdk through IntelliJ

Tags: ruby, macos, intellij-idea, rspec, rubygems

I am trying to get a project to work that was created through RubyMine. I have an ultimate version of IntelliJ and would rather use that with the Ruby plugin to run these tests.

However when I attempt to run I get an error saying "No Rspec gem found in SDK". I havent

My Gem environment looks like this:

```
mac:~ cmietzner$ gem environment

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.7
- RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/colemietzner/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
   - /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
   - /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
   - /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin
   - /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /usr/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /sbin
   - /usr/local/git/bin
   - /Users/colemietzner/.rvm/bin
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that IntelliJ created your mobile as a Java-oriented module.  One can tell by the little blue square next to the module name.

This fixed it for me:

1. Open **Project Structure**
2. Click on **Modules** under **Project Settings**
3. Delete the module (via **-**)
4. Add a new module, and choose **Ruby** (or rails, or whatever you need)

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question but I ran into the same problem and solved it as follows:

**The Problem:**

In the intelliJ configuration screen shown in the screenshot above (found in "Run" > "edit configurations"), you can see the configuration is trying to "Choose the SDK from the module".  And of course there are no Ruby binaries inside the module (the project directory) so it throws the "No SDK found" error.

[image: IntelliJ snapshot]

**The solution:**

(Assuming all the appropriate gems have been `$ bundle install`'d) I found the solution was to select "Use other SDK and 'rspec' gem:" and choose the appropriate SDK. **BUT** to ensure this applies to the whole project, I replicated this change in "Defaults" configuration for both Ruby and RSpec.

e.g for Ruby settings:

[image: IntelliJ Run Configurations screenshot - Ruby Defaults]

and for RSpec settings:
[image]